# How to stop the status bar covering the navigation bar in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

This is my issue....

[image]

This happens when:

1. Status bar is faded out using the button.
2. Rotate 180 deg from landscape to upside-down landscape.
3. Status bar is faded back in using the button. - it now covers the navigation bar.

The button code to toggle the status bar visibility:

```
- (IBAction)toggleBar:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"View Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));

    // Toggle status bar visiblity
    BOOL isStatusBarHidden = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:!isStatusBarHidden
                                            withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}
```

The view always reports its frame to be 480 x 288.

The issue was fixable on iOS 5 using a hacky workaround, by stopping the rotation filling the space.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden])
    {
        float oldAlpha = self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.01;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

        double delayInSeconds = 0.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = oldAlpha;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
        });
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

This dons't work on iOS 6 because `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not called.  However, using its replacement: `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` also dosn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: The replacement for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`. It is `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed, but In ios 5 it had anouther purpose - to let you know it is about to rotate the screen.

Comment: that isn't true. A call to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` was never an indication that the view controller was about to rotate. Its purpose was to ask whether certain rotations were allowed. The `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method is used to indicate that a rotation is actually about to happen. Remember, these methods are about the view controller, not the screen.

Comment: @rmaddy - Ok apparently you are correct!  `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is also called on iOS 5.  I thought it was a new method for iOS 6.

Comment: `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` has existed since iOS 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

After status bar is toggled, Set your self.view.frame again.

Comment: This didn't work.  The frame is always reported as 480 x 268 (before/after rotation/togging status bar).  Setting the frame has no effect.  Thank you for your answer tho.

Comment: did you check my another solution?

Answer (score 0):

At IOS6, you should use these methods. Check these out.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    //returns true if want to allow orientation change
    return TRUE;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{   
     //decide number of origination tob supported by Viewcontroller.
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //from here you Should try to Preferred orientation for ViewController 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer was to use the same hack on `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` I had said this would not work in my question, but I just tried it again and it did the trick.

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

        double delayInSeconds = 0.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I call

dismissViewControllerAnimated

this method, and then call

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];

this problem appear.

When I call 
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
 first, no problem.